# render a partial on ajax:success in coffeescript in rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, coffeescript

I am trying to render a partial after ajax call using coffee script but could not make it.

**Controller which is called on AJAX request**

```
 def unfollow
     @user = User.find(params[:follow][:followed_id])
     current_user.unfollow!(@user)
     render json: {result: "success"}
 end
```

**partial: User/follow.html.erb**

```
 <div id="follow_button">
   <%=form_for(:follow,url: follow_users_path,remote:true) do |f| %>
     <%= f.hidden_field :followed_id, value: @user.id %>
     <%= f.submit "Follow", id: "Follow_button", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
   <% end %>
 </div>
```

**Ajax:success function**

```
 $ ->
     $('#unfollow_button').on "ajax:success", (e,data,status,xhr)  ->
     $('#follow_unfollow_button').html("<%= escape_javascript( render partial: 'users/follow') %>")
```

**HTML which is on That place**

```
 <div id="unfollow_button">
      <%=form_for(:follow,url: unfollow_users_path,remote:true) do |f| %>
      <%= f.hidden_field :followed_id, value: @user.id %>
      <%= f.submit "Unfollow", id: "unfollow_button", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
      <% end %>
 </div>
```

I am not getting any value from the server I just want to render it when ajax success. But it render like this

```
    <%= escape_javascript( render partial: 'users/follow') %>
```

How to solve this? what am I missing?

Comment: What does your controller action look like? Also what file does the ajax:success function exist inside of?

Comment: @MikeDoyle i have added those on my answer

Comment: I updated with an answer. Please let me know if it worked for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah you can't render an erb partial inside javascript from a json response like that. Here's how to fix

1) remove this line from the controller

```
render json: {result: "success"}
```

2) In views/users/ create a file called `unfollow.js.coffee` with the following code

```
$('#follow_unfollow_button').html("<%= j render('users/follow') %>")
```

3) You no longer need to bind to ajax success function so delete this code completely from wherever you had it

```
 $ ->
     $('#unfollow_button').on "ajax:success", (e,data,status,xhr)  ->
     $('#follow_unfollow_button').html("<%= escape_javascript( render partial: 'users/follow') %>")
```

Comment: i have some doubt in these steps. what should i return on the controller ?. if i remove ajax:success then how can i say when to render this?

Comment: Rails controller action try to render templates named the same as their action. It's a pretty basic UJS implementation that I use sometimes in my apps. See this page http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html and the Server Side Concerns section

Answer (score 2):

Don't try to render it from the coffeescript in this case. Instead, render the result from controller and return that as data to ajax.

1)  Change controller method to

```
def unfollow
     @user = User.find(params[:follow][:followed_id])
     current_user.unfollow!(@user)
     render 'users/follow', :layout => false
 end
```

2) Change JS function to

```
$ ->
     $('#unfollow_button').on "ajax:success", (e,data,status,xhr)  ->
     $('#follow_unfollow_button').html(data)
```

As your controller will return something (and not an error), the ajax:success will fire up and instead of trying to render it in JS/coffeescript, just render it in controller and that way, you also don't need to render something just for the sake of returning information to client.